# Pass a parameter to SQL server SP with quotes

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, parameters, sqlcommand

I am executing a stored procedure on a SQL server using a SqlCommand class from C#. Currently I just build an execution string that parses in the parameter values to the stored procedure then executes the string on the server. The problem is when I have quotes the string does not get passed properly

Is it possible to use SqlParameter objects to pass in the parameters without worrying about escaping out of quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the preferred way of sending parameters.

Example:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SomeProcedure", connection) {
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 42;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).Value = "A string value";
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, yes - and you should be using SqlParameter objects rather than string concatenation anyway, as a minimum to guard against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Sounds like a job for little Bobby Tables.

Answer (score 0):

When using SqlParameter you are able to specify the type and size of the parameters.  Doing so ensures execution plan re-use (though that's not such an issue with StoredProcs) but also ensure that you do not need to worry about escaping and quoting - it's all done for you.